# Simpler way to find the file that define my C/C++ function / macro than 'grep'

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I start to work on a huge project with tones of C and C++ files, already wrote by someone else.

Is there any faster/simpler ways to find in what file any macro or function is define other than a `grep -r` ? It is kind of long.

In some IDE there is this *magical* thing like right click and "go to definition". But I'm currently using emacs. I don't know if there is any customisation that can do this ?
Each time, I have to copy past the name in my terminal, run a `grep` and re copy past the file path in my emacs. (And you know, I am lazy...)

Comment: While I really like emacs (and use emacs key bindings whenever available in an IDE), I'd still recommend rather switching to some IDE. You'd profit from such goto definition functionality as well as quite a lot of other stuff (GUI to debugger, ...). I personally favour eclipse (especially for providing emacs KB), but there are quite a lot of other good ones.

Comment: if `grep -r` is too long for you, try [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) ;)

Comment: I don't use emacs, but it looks like it can read a tags file generated by [ExuberantCtags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to mimic the "go to definition" functionality of IDEs.  The emacs wiki has a page about [how to generate](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags) such a file.

Comment: @Aconcagua I haven't used emacs, but old-school editor could be as convenient as an IDE. In vim, plugin like YouCompleteMe has all c++ semantics ability(clang backend).

Comment: @liliscent Feels a bit like turning an OSE *into* an IDE, at least partially... How far do you get with vim (not familiar with myself now...) "out of the box"?

Comment: Make a tags file with `etags` or whatever, and then `M-.` to jump to the definition of a symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTags. You can try using Ctags with emacs and it will help you to navigate to the function declaration directly. For its usage, please refer to https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags

You can also explore Cscope, It has a better feature set than ctags which works directly on pattern recognition. But sometimes, you just need to navigate through code and more often than not ctags does the job.

Answer (score 2):

> Each time, I have to copy past the name in my terminal, run a `grep` and re copy past the file path in my emacs.

You can improve on this by using `M-x rgrep` inside Emacs. It asks for the regular expression, a glob pattern of files to look in, and a directory to start in.  It then does a recursive grep, outputs the results in a buffer, and you can jump directly from the hits to the corresponding file.

For the glob pattern, you could type something like `*.c`, or you could use one of the aliases defined in the variable `grep-files-aliases`.  For example, `ch` is equivalent to `*.[ch]` (C source and header files) and `cchh` is equivalent to `*.cc *.[ch]xx *.[ch]pp *.[CHh] *.CC *.HH *.[ch]++` (C++ source and header files).

You might find that this works well enough that you don't need ctags and other tools suggested in the other answers and comments.

---

For ease of finding function definitions in C, some projects use the convention that the function name in the definition starts in the first column:

```
/* this is just a declaration */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

/* in the definition, the function name starts on its own line */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
```

That means that you can find the definition, excluding any calls to the function, with the regex `^main`.

Comment: code looks ugly for your second paragraph but thx for the first one :)

Answer (score 1):

`grep` should be really fast if you limit the search to the directories and file types (generally `.h` and `.hpp`) that are likely to contain it. For example if you know it is in your application just search there, if you know it's from FreeType (generally `FT_*`) search there.

More RAM will help the system cache files better, and if your on a HDD best to get an SSD. If your working directly on a VM, especially one with remote disks, if can work locally that will often be faster.

Otherwise many fully functional IDE's (Visual Studio, XCode, Eclipse, etc.) have C++ integration to keep track of these things, and will for example offer a "Go to declaration" and "Go to definition" option as a shortcut or context menu when over a symbol.

Comment: `grep` is fast but is kind of long to use (double copy past)